# error: expected ')' before 'Bombs'

Tags: objective-c, xcode

```
- (void)registerBombs:(Bombs*)bombs {
    [bombs addObject:bombs];
}
```

`error: expected ')' before 'Bombs'` 
it shows up twice here.
Help please

**UPDATE MORE ERRORS:**

> error: expected ')' before 'Lane'

It shows up twice here.

.m:

```
//
//  Game.m
//  Pong
//
//  Created by Rohan Kapur on 4/30/11.
//  Copyright 2011 UWCSEA. All rights reserved.
//

#import "Game.h"
#import "Person.h"
#import "GameScreen.h"


@implementation Game

-(void)awakeFromNib { bombs = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10]
                                   retain];
    lanes = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:3] retain];

}
-(void)registerLane:(Lane*)lane { [lanes addObject:lane];  - error:expected ')' before 'Lane' , it shows up twice here.

}

-(void)registerBombs:(Bombs*)bombs {
    [bombs addObject:bombs];
}



-(void) update:(CADisplayLink*)sender {


}
@end
```

.h:

```
@class GameScreen;

@interface Game : NSObject {

    NSMutableArray* bombs;
    GameScreen* viewController;
    NSMutableArray* lanes;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet GameScreen* viewController;

@end
```

Comment: There is no error in this line. Most probably you are missing something in your code above this function may be a ; or ).

Comment: post the source code of whole file then

Comment: ok i will update my post

Comment: Do you realise that `[bombs addObject:bombs];` adds `bombs` to itself?

Comment: im using a book to help me so im pretty unsure

Comment: You haven’t pasted the declaration of the `Bomb` class. Do you have one? From your code, you should also have a `Lane` class.

Answer (score 2):

This error crops up because the compiler doesn't know what `Bomb` is.  Presumably you have a `Bomb.h` file in your project, which means you need to make sure that:

```
#import "Bomb.h"
```

...is at the top of this file.

If you don't have a "Bomb.h" file, then you need to find where you have `@interface Bomb : ...`, and `#import` *that* file.